# Need Advice on Complex Customized Magento 2 Shop

Tags: extensions, magento-community, performance, programming, customizable-options

Products: 900~
Specific Features: 55 to 60
3rd party Extensions required: 20 to 30
Customization required: Theme, Extension, default Magento logic

**Could you please advice me based on your experience.**

I'm concerned what should be the balance between following(i.e, relative preference, what should be more, what should be less, what should be avoided):

1. 3rd party extensions
2. customizing theme front end
3. customizing 3rd party extensions
4. customizing default magento logic(when not possible via Admin Panel)

Criteria:

- performance
- compatibiltiy issue
- avoiding rework
- being able to upgrade Magento + Extensions + Theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a website on parameters: performance, compatibility issue etc then and you must have expert level knowledge on Magento 2 Development and have to follow magento2 code stranded during development time and highly understand on Magento 2 architecture. Then you can do complex customized on magento2 at right way.

**According to your requirement the balance should be as follow:**

1. Customizing default magento logic(when not possible via Admin Panel)
2. customizing theme front end
3. 3rd party extensions
4. customizing 3rd party extensions
5. Optimized the code and logic of 3rd party extensions

Comment: can we have answers in readable English please?

Comment: Thanks for notifying my mistake on  spell and other. I have updated answer. You can check it .

Comment: Hi @AmitBera, thanks for responding. By Balance, I meant, what should be less & what should be more. For example, if as per recommended Balance, I should prefer creating extensions rather than customizing default magento logic, then even if something can easily done by tweaking magento logic, I would create extensions.